# Using Plex font in Sharelatex?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, sharelatex

I would like to know how to use the IBM Plex font is Sharelatex.

Therefore, I tried two approaches:

1: https://ctan.org/pkg/plex-otf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{plex-otf}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing  
elit.   Etiam  lobortisfacilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et 
neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. 
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales...

\end{document}
```

2: https://ctan.org/pkg/plex

Inserted before \begin{document}

```
\usepackage{plex-serif}
\usepackage{plex-sans}
\usepackage{plex-mono}
```

Both without success. In each case, I uploaded the respective folders and files from the zip files into my sharelatex project. Could you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Your code should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You need to upload the font itself to your project.

Comment: I uploaded everything from the respective zip files, including the fonts..

Comment: The zip file does not contain the font.

Comment: With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you don't need package `inputenc`.  With a recent pdflatex, you don't need `inputenc` as well.

Comment: As described here https://ctan.org/pkg/plex-otf you need to get the fonts themselves from github.

Comment: Upload the fonts, use fontspec, and you're done. See here: https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/04/02/using-your-favourite-fonts-with-sharelatex.html